# In MySQL, how to copy rows of two tables within the same table respectably using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `questions` and `answers` and would like to copy the rows of each table into the same table using PHP. The structure of the tables are as follows:

**Table: questions**

[image]

**Table: answers**

[image]

Currently I am using following code but it is not working:

```
include "db.php";    
$exam_title=$_POST["title_id"];
$exam_id=$_POST["exam"];
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "insert into questions(question, option_type, media_type, media_link, exam_id)
    select question, option_type, media_type, media_link, '$exam_id' from questions where exam_id = ". $exam_id;   

$sql2 = "insert into answers(answer, ques_id, right_ans)
    select a.answer, q.ques_id, a.right_ans from questions q, answers a where q.exam_id = ". $exam_id;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "done";    
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}    
if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo "done2";    
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}    
$conn->close();
```

The issue is `ques_id` of the `questions` table and `ans_id` of `answers` table is `primary key` and is `auto increment` where `ques_id` of `answers` and `ques_id` of `questions` have relation.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: It is returning done done2 (the success message) but stuffs are not getting copied.

Comment: Maybe autocommit is disabled. That's why you should commit before closing connection.

Comment: I'd check it is already active (enabled)

Comment: what does the select statement return if you run it separately?

Comment: You should check your conditions `where exam_id = ". $exam_id`  i.e. whether they actually select any row.

Comment: @YoramdeLangen actually not. He wants to build up new refences between the newly inserted rows in questions and anserw in the way that a new copy of a question not gets related to an "old" but to the newly inserted answer in the second step. Can't be achieved with two copy statements

Comment: Then how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply copyiing records in both tables which have a 1:1 relationship. and "questions" obviously is the master, you have new questions, all showing to the existing answers (i.e. two questions showing to just one single answer) and "dangling" answers not having any questions.

From my perspective, having a question twice but only one answer is what I call "normalization", but anyway, if you want to copy the entire set, you need (pseudo code)

```
Get all fields for all questions and their related answers (simple join)
for each row
   insert new question row
   get last insert id
   insert answer, set answer.ques_id to last insert id of question
```